# PHP to delete SQL but still shows

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

I'm using php to display what I have in my data base of user name.
When I want to delete the user name it works and deletes it from the database but it still shows in my php page.

Heres the delete command I'm using:

```
<table class="table">
                <tr><th>#</th><th>Date</th><th>ID</th><th>Actions</th></tr><?php
            if ($_GET['a'] == 'delete' && $_GET['i']) {
                $UserId = $_GET['i'];
                $res=mysql_query("SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");
                $TraderId=mysql_result($res,0,"TraderId");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `traders` WHERE `TraderId`=$TraderId");
                echo '<br><br><div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Bye bye!</strong> Result has been deleted.</div>';
            }
            if($_GET['s']=="true")
{
echo '<br><br><div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> The user has been saved.</div>';    
}
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
            for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($res); $i++) {
                $Username = mysql_result($res, $i, "Username");
                $UserId = mysql_result($res, $i, "UserId");
                $IsAdmin = (string) (bool) mysql_result($res, $i, "IsAdmin");
                echo "<tr><td>$UserId</td><td>$Username</td><td>$IsAdmin</td><td>
    <a href=\"users.php?a=delete&i=$UserId\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</a>
        <a href=\"user.php?i=$UserId\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
            }
            ?>    
        </table>
```

and here is where the names should show .. this is the trader page where the `TraderId` is displayed:

```
    <table border="">
    <head><tr><th style="padding-bottom:40px; padding-right:70px; padding-top:20px;">Date</th><th style="padding-left:200px; float:right;">Screenshots</th></tr></thead>
<?php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `traders`");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++)
{   
$Name=mysql_result($res,$i,"Name");
$Price=mysql_result($res,$i,"Price");
$Timezone=mysql_result($res,$i,"Timezone");    
$TraderId=mysql_result($res,$i,"TraderId"); 

echo '<tbody><tr><td style="padding-left:0px;padding-bottom:10px;">'.$Name.'</td><td style="padding-left:200px;"><a href="details.php?i='.$TraderId.'">View details<a/></td></tr></tbody>';
}
?>
        </table>
```

Again the delete function works as I see the result been removed from my sql database  but not from the output page.

Comment: Most likely this is going to be a cache issue, or the record didn't actually get deleted OR, you deleted the wrong record.

Comment: i take that back, it doesnt get deleted from the traders table

Comment: When it comes to issues like this, I like to go right back to the SQL. Do a select (command line or PHPMyAdmin, or whatever your preference is) and see if you can manually pull the data record. Copy and paste the sql from your code to be sure. If it still pulls the data, your record must not have been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");
```

select what?

Guessing the delete users works as it gets the id from $_GET, where as the traders never actually gets any data from mysql query.

EDIT - longer explanation
The delete users works as your userid used on the delete query is provided without needing the select:

```
$UserId = $_GET['i'];
```

The delete traders wont work because you did not select anything to get the traders id from the user id to use on the delete query

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");
                $TraderId=mysql_result($res,0,"TraderId");
```

ie "SELECT FROM users" - select WHAT?

Comment: i have a table named users and the delete function works fine on that table but it doesnt work on the traders table.

when a user makes a new account it automaticly creates record in users and in traders

Comment: i guess thats where im wrong because i have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: try changing this "$res=mysql_query("SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");" to this "$res=mysql_query("SELECT `TraderId` FROM `users` WHERE `UserId`=$UserId");"

Comment: wow. thanks  worked like a charm. i dont know how to thank you james and this subject is resolved

Comment: np. try echoing out vars when you come across this in the future. eg your "$TraderId" would not have been what you expected. Also, use mysql error reporting when debugging. This will likely have returned an error as there's no select_expr